# Z-Index and iFrames

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am embedding simple html and css that i've written into another application using an iframe. Within my code, I am using CSS to create context menus when you hover over elements of the page. When I get close to the edge of the iframe with the hover menu, however, it gets cut-off and stays below the frame. I've tried many different variations of z-index, but nothing has worked. Is there a way to get this menu to show above the parent window?

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

Any positions and rules for belonging to the CSS stacking context are limited to the current document.  This can't work using `z-index`, since the `iframe`-contents are a complete different document. You can't have anything "bleed" out of an frame. If you want to have an overlay, don't use an `iframe` at all.